# virtualbox - debian with no-ip

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I have VB on my XP SP3. I am running one guest OS, Debian. I installed it using the 150MB, and everything seems to work fine.
I am using 3.1.6 VB

The purpose of this server is running php, mysql and django project.

So I need access both locally and externally.
I usually do it with my no-ip. I have experience with Ubuntu server, and using noip2 was a cake.

I had this "domain" xxx.no-ip.org.
I need this to be use on my debian server, so that I can type xxx.no-ip.org into the firefox (on my xp).

I checked ifconfig, pstree. They showed that debian grabbed the right ip (it matched with my ip), and pstree showed noip2 has already been activated (under init.d)

But I can't access to xxx.no-ip.org from my windows in firefox
how come?

back in the days when I used ubuntu as its own installation (instead of VM), noip2 worked like a cake without any twist.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not really a programming question, but have u configured port forwarding from your host to the vm?

http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/12/17/configure-port-forwarding-to-a-virtualbox-guest-os/

Comment: life saver! got it done! lol yeah, i did a search before asking, and had read this kind of quesitons posted here. so i guessed worth a try (since stack is full of elite!!!)